# How to add a "lock" button that links two sliders together in Interface builder?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, interface-builder

I want to add a button that when pressed will lock two sliders together such that the values for the two sliders will always be the same.

I have a solution for this using code, but I'm wondering if there is a way to do this with interface builder alone.

I am worried that the code based solution that one slider may lag behind the other in high CPU utilization environments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this with Interface Builder alone.

Actually everything becomes code in the end, as far as I understand, Interface Builder was built to improve the development time, not necessarily to improve performance, I found this interesting quote on Apple's site about NIBs:

> Xcode works in conjunction with these frameworks to help you connect
>   the controls of your user interface **to the objects in your project
>   that respond to those controls**.

Taking into account that, everything will become code (of some level). [About NIB files](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html).

> At runtime, these descriptions are used to recreate the objects and
>   their configuration inside your application. When you load a nib file
>   at runtime, you get an exact replica of the objects that were in your
>   Xcode document. The nib-loading code instantiates the objects,
>   configures them, and reestablishes any inter-object connections that
>   you created in your nib file.

If you would really want to avoid such behavior probably the best you would be able to do is create the widget from scratch, but that would be a totally different question.

<strike>Just curious, why wouldn't you want to use code?</strike>

Comment: Well, the other slider will always lag behind as the best the code can do is update the other slider when the first one moves. While this probably wouldn't be noticeable, if the process was running at a low nice and the CPU was busy it might be visible.

Comment: Oh, I see. Hmmm well I would recommend you to add that to your question, it changes completely the type of answers you might get, I'm interested and I will edit my answer.

Comment: If the CPU is so busy that it can't keep up with mouse movements (relatively slow when you see the world in gigahertz), you've got other problems. Besides: anything you did in IB would be subject to the same laws of physics, and would also have problems when the CPU is overloaded.

Comment: I'm not sure, it probably would depend if the graphics card is running the drawing process or if the processor is the one taking charge of that work. I was just reading this post about Quartz on Matt Gallagher's blog. Might be worth a reading if you are interested in the topic. http://cocoawithlove.com/2011/03/mac-quartzgl-2d-drawing-on-graphics.html

Comment: You guys are WAY overanalyzing this. This is done all the time.

Answer (score 2):

Locking the two sliders together in IB is easy. And I've never seen lag.  Having that lock dependent on the press of a button is another story, that would have to be done in code, but it would not be too complicated. Assuming you have outlets connected in IB and declared in the controller

```
-(IBAction)lockSliders:(id)sender {
    [slider1 setContinuous:YES];
    [slider1 takeIntegerValueFrom:slider2]; // or takeFloatValueFrom or takeDoubleValueFrom
    [slider2 setContinuous:YES];
    [slider2 takeIntegerValueFrom:slider1];
 }
```